# My carousel enlarges and shrinks when it cycles to 3rd slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a carousel of 3 slides. When it cycles to 3rd slide it enlarges and gets overlapped. The first two slides work but not the last slide.

My code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides-->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="" alt="myimage1" style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Your news title</h3>
                            <p>news in short</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="" alt="myimage2" style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Your news title</h3>
                            <p>news in short</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="" alt="myimage3" style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Your news title</h3>
                            <p>news in short</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and Right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In css:

```
.carousel.inner > .item > img {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
}
```

Here are the screenshots for more clarification:

slide 1:
[image]

slide 2:

[image]

slide 3:

[image]

In the third slide you can see the image is enlarged and for 1st two slides size is perfect. How can I fix this.

Comment: What are the original image sizes? It appears to me, that they have different aspect ratios and therefore the last image gets "too big". A quick fix would be to crop the images to all have the same size using a tool similar to Photoshop or GIMP. Then, of course, there's a way to crop them using CSS. Furthermore there's probably a typo in your CSS because you seem to mean to write `.carousel-inner > .item > img` (with dash instead of . between carousel and inner)

Comment: @dlaxar But these are images from JSON data I cannot use photoshop. What changes should I do in CSS.

Comment: have you tried my suggested edit to the CSS?

Comment: @dlaxar I have made the changes as you told it works fine but now it doesn't cycles automatically why is this happening.

Comment: @dlaxar please add your answer(I have upvoted your comment add that as your answer). I want to upvote you as you have fixed me issue Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer. Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the original image sizes? It appears to me, that they have different aspect ratios and therefore the last image gets "too big".

A quick fix would be to crop the images to all have the same size using a tool similar to Photoshop or GIMP.

Then, of course, there's a way to crop them using CSS. There's probably a typo in your CSS because you seem to mean to write `.carousel-inner > .item > img` (with dash instead of . between carousel and inner)

(this was copied & edited from the comment as requested by @rock stone)

Answer (score 1):

you need to make all the picture for your slider on the same resolution using a photo editor but if you cant change the resolution of the picture
try to put `max-width` and `max-height` instead of `width` and `height`

Comment: I am using `attr()` in jquery to set imageURL to `src=""` as dlaxar said I have done it and it works but now carousel doesn't cycle automatically.

Comment: do you mean you need to click on next / previouse to see the next image ?

Comment: Yes I need to click it. I have made the necessay changes as told by dlaxar but now it doesn't slides automatically.

Comment: I have fixed the issue Thanks for your help.

Comment: try to initialize your carousel via Jquery instead of data-ride="carousel" use $("#myCarousel").carousel(); , also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146990/discussion-between-rock-stone-and-abdeslem-charif).